# How to ignore the request body match for an specific host in rspec VCR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, vcr

I have ElasticSearch and Kibana integration with my rails application, and i use they for log and measure requests to external API's. I don't want that VCR match the body for ElasticSearch requests records, because there are a "current time" (created_at) field in every log, that breaks VCR older records.

This is my current configuration

```rb
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'

  vcr_mode = ENV['VCR_MODE'] =~ /rec/i ? :all : :once

  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.default_cassette_options[:record] = vcr_mode
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end
```

This is the log method in my custom REST client.

```rb
  def log(method, params, response, comments:)
    Rails.logger.info(response.inspect)

    Elastic::LogServices
      .log_request(comments,
                   method: method,
                   source: ENV['HOSTNAME'],
                   url: response.env.url.to_s,
                   header: response.env.request_headers,
                   body: params,
                   type: :out,
                   response_header: response.headers,
                   response_body: response.body,
                   response_status: response.status)
  end
```

In the log services...

```rb
    def self.log_request(comments = '',
                         created_at: nil,
                         method:,
                         source:,
                         url:,
                         header:,
                         body:,
                         type:,
                         response_header:,
                         response_body: '?',
                         response_status:,
                         format: 'REST')
      log =
        Elastic::Request::Log
        .new(created_at: created_at,
             method: method,
             source: source,
             url: url,
             header: header,
             body: JSON.pretty_generate(body),
             type: type,
             response:
              {
                header: response_header,
                body: JSON.pretty_generate(response_body),
                status: response_status
              },
             format: format,
             comments: comments)

      Elastic::Request::LogJob.perform_async(log)
    end
```

This field is in the log entity class

```rb
        @created_at = created_at || Time.now.utc.iso8601
```

Also, i dont want to Mock the "Time.now.utc.iso8601" method, because there are a lot of tests that i have to change. The application do a lot of requests to others APIs.

Anyway to configure VCR to ignore the body match for all "elasticsearch:9200" requests?

Comment: You can use [`timecop gem`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to freeze time at certain point

Comment: Or you can write custom matcher to ignore `created_at` field in response body. Check out [`this article`](https://railsware.com/blog/2013/10/03/custom-vcr-matchers-for-dealing-with-mutable-http-requests/)

Comment: Or you can match on other attributes to ignore body matching since its changing every time. Check out [`request-matching docs`](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/3-0-3/docs/request-matching).
As you can see you have lots of options to choose from

Comment: I solved the problem mocking the "save" method of all my "ElasticRepository" instances in test environment with "before(:all)". Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/fixtures/vcr_cassettes'
  c.register_request_matcher :body do |request1, request2|
    if request1.uri.include?('<your_host>')
      true
    else
      CGI.escape(request1.body) == CGI.escape(request2.body)
    end
  end

  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.configure_rspec_metadata!
end
```